# Azure backp of workstation fails. No data is transferring to the cloud

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I am backing up a workstation to an Azure backup vault.  This used to work but recently it stopped.
It seems that a backup job is running but never completing.  Once this happens every scheduled backup fails because of the previous backup still running.

THe scratch directory \Program Files\Microsoft Azure Backup\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Recovery Services Agent\Scratch\VHDs\
Has three VHDs, one of which is quite old (from December), the other two are from today.

I'm wondering if that old VHD is gumming things up.
Should I just remove it?  Actually that's not so simple because when I tried I was told that it was open by "system" and I couldn'e delete it.

Comment: More information on this issue.

Comment: More information on this issue.
The Azure reecovery agent running as CBEngine claims through the management snap in to be "Transferring data (unoptimized may take more time)"  However when I run netstat I see that cbengine only has local loopback sockets connected.  Presumably these are copying a disk image to the shadow copy which is mounted as a virtual disk.  There is no data passing over the Internet uplink.